# Session variables not working in PHP after UBUNTU upgrade

Tags: php

In error log, i get error on line 7 and 109 of header.php which says "on line 7 Undefined index: id in /var/www/ttm.com/public_html/include/header.php" and "Undefined index: fullname in /var/www/ttm.com/public_html/include/header.php on line 109". This same code was working fine before the upgrade.

Here is my code of header.php

```
<?php
    include('data/db.php');
    $base_url = "http://ttm.xceedance.com/";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
        header("Location:login.php");
    } 
    $user_id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $sql_works = "select  *  from items where work_status!='Start' AND account_id='$user_id'";
    $result_works = mysql_query($sql_works);
    $acco_data=mysql_fetch_array($result_works);
    if(!empty($acco_data))
    {
        $account_work_status=$acco_data['work_status'];
    }
    else
    {
        $sql_mett = "select  *  from meeting where work_status!='Start' AND account_id='$user_id'";
        $result_mett = mysql_query($sql_mett);
        $acco_mett=mysql_fetch_array($result_mett);
        if(empty($acco_mett))
       { 
         $sql_client = "select  *  from client_email where work_status!='Start' AND account_id='$user_id'";
         $result_client = mysql_query($sql_client);
         $acco_client=mysql_fetch_array($result_client);
         if(empty($acco_client))
         { 
             $sql_break = "select  *  from break where work_status!='Start' AND account_id='$user_id'";
             $result_break = mysql_query($sql_break);
             $acco_break=mysql_fetch_array($result_break);
             if(!empty($acco_break)) 
             { 
                $account_work_status=$acco_break['work_status'];
             }  else {   $account_work_status='Start'; }
         }
         else
           {

         $account_work_status=$acco_client['work_status'];
           }
       }
       else
       {

        $account_work_status=$acco_mett['work_status'];
       }
    }
    //print_r($account_work_status);die;


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120" >
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Xceedance Exposure Management Time Tracker</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <html><body><div id="image" style="float:left;"><?php if($account_work_status=='Start') { ?><a href="index.php"><?php }  else { ?><a href="#workstatus_modal" data-toggle="modal"><?php }  ?><img src="/images/logo.png"/></div></body></html>
                <html><?php if($account_work_status=='Start') { ?><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><?php }  else { ?><a href="#workstatus_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="navbar-brand"><?php }  ?>Exposure Management Time Tracker</a><html>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">                                
                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['fullname'] ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">           
                        <li>
                           <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="chpass.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i>Change Password</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                           <?php if($account_work_status=='Start') { ?> <a href="logout.php"><?php }  else { ?><a href="#workstatus_modal" data-toggle="modal"><?php }  ?><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
```

Comment: first please do this `header("Location:login.php");exit();` There is no point executing any further PHP if you need to redirect to the login page. Second, does `data/db.php` or anywhere else include a `session_start()` call?

Comment: @Scuzzy I added @session_start(); in db.php already. Still not working.

Comment: You're going to have to review your login.php yourself to make sure its building your session correctly. All I can tell is that step is not working if `$_SESSION['login']` is set but `$_SESSION['id']` is not